# What ports to use for apache

Tags: mysql, apache, server, xampp

I am quite new to servers and the like and download xampp but it comes up with this error: [image]

I have already uninstalled skype but still throws this error. What other ports could I use for apache (main port and SSL port)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check what service is using the port:

1. Open the CMD with Administrator rights
2. type:  `netstat -aon | findstr :80`
3. type: `tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 1604"` "1604" its the Process ID its the number of the last column.

[image]

this answer is intended as a help, you can change the port number for apache but it could be a pain later since other programs assume it will be 80 by default, also from your image if you find there is nothing using the port it could be

> missing dependencies, improper privilegies, a crash or a shutdown by another method.

Just type `event viewer` in your start menu search and open it:

[image]

there you should find the log which would have more info as to why apache is shutting down (this is very useful for any error you have).